# Binding Enums in Viewmodels to MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums

Whenever I try to create a ticket my ticket priority is also LOW. I've setup a drop down list for Priority but the assignment of priorities on Tickets doesn't seem to be working. I'm suspecting it has to do with my Views\Ticket\Create.cshtml

I need some clarifications to see if I'm doing this correctly:

Do I need both

In my models I have a class called Ticket and it has enum Priority

```
public enum Priority
{
    Low, Med, High
}
public class Ticket
{
  ....
}
```

Configuration.cs (snippet for inserting ticket data)

```
var tickets = new List<Ticket>
{
    new Ticket {
        UserID = users.Single(s => s.LastName == "Wan").UserID,
        CategoryID = categories.Single(c => c.CategoryName == "Con-X" ).CategoryID,
        Issue = ("Con-X Login Error"),
        Priority = Priority.High
    },
    new Ticket {
        UserID = users.Single(s => s.LastName == "Wan").UserID,
        CategoryID = categories.Single(c => c.CategoryName == "Desktop" ).CategoryID,
        Issue = ("Can't remote access C0123"),
        Priority = Priority.Med
    },
};
```

In my viewmodel TicketVM I've also setup enum for Priority as well.
Since I'm configuring my tickets through this:

```
            Ticket ticket = new Ticket
            {
                UserID = (int)WebSecurity.CurrentUserId,
                Issue = model.Issue,
                IssuedTo = model.IssuedTo,
                CategoryID = model.CategoryID,
                Priority = model.priority <-- ERROR
            };
```

Error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.ViewModels.TicketVM.Priority' to
>   'RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models.Priority'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
>   RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem

Views\Ticket\Create.cshtml

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.priority, Model.PriorityList, "Please select the priority") 
    </div>
```

ViewModels\TicketVM.cs

```
public class TicketVM
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the description")]
    public string Issue { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Administrator")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select the Administrator")]
    public int IssuedTo { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AdministratorList { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoryList { get; set; }

    public enum Priority
    {
        LOW = 3,
        MED = 2,
        HIGH = 1,
    }

    public Priority priority { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PriorityList
    {
        get
        {
            var priorityType = typeof(Priority);
            var priorityValues = Enum.GetValues(priorityType).Cast<Priority>();
            var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(priorityType);

            return
                from priorityValue in priorityValues
                select new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = converter.ConvertToString(priorityValue),
                    Value = priorityValue.ToString(),
                };
        }
    }
}
```

TicketController.cs

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    TicketVM model = new TicketVM();
    ConfigureViewModel(model);
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(TicketVM model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        model.CategoryList = new SelectList(db.Categories, "CategoryID", "CategoryName");
        ConfigureViewModel(model);
        return View(model);
    }
    Ticket ticket = new Ticket
    {
        UserID = (int)WebSecurity.CurrentUserId,
        Issue = model.Issue,
        IssuedTo = model.IssuedTo,
        CategoryID = model.CategoryID,
        Priority = model.priority <-- ERROR
    };
    db.Tickets.Add(ticket);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

private void ConfigureViewModel(TicketVM model)
{
    IEnumerable<User> admins = db.Users.Where(u => u.IsAdministrator).OrderBy(u => u.LastName);
    model.AdministratorList = admins.Select(a => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = a.UserID.ToString(),
        Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", a.FirstMidName, a.LastName)
    });
    IEnumerable<Category> categories = db.Categories.OrderBy(u => u.CategoryName);
    model.CategoryList = categories.Select(a => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = a.CategoryID.ToString(),
        Text = a.CategoryName.ToString()
    });
}
```

Comment: You have still not deleted the `model.CategoryList = new SelectList(...)` line of code in the POST method :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `enums` in your `Ticket` model and `TicketVM` model are not the same.

One option would be to add a using statement in `TicketVM` so that you use the `enum` from `RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models` (and delete the `enum` definition in your `TicketVM` class)

```
@using RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models
public class TicketVM
{
    ....
    public Priority priority { get; set; } // uses the enum from the Models assembly
}
```

Another option would be to cast from one to the other. Since you need this inside a object initializer, create a private method in the controller to cast the value

```
private Models.Priority CastPriority(ViewModels.TicketVM.Priority value)
{
    Models.Priority priority = Models.Priority.Low;
    Enum.TryParse<Models.Priority>(value.ToString(), out priority);
    return priority;
}
```

and inside the object initializer

```
Ticket ticket = new Ticket
{
    ....
    CategoryID = model.CategoryID,
    Priority = CastPriority(model.priority)
};
```

Side note: You can simplify the code for generating the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` to

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PriorityList
{
    get
    {
        return Enum.GetNames(typeof(Proprity)).Select(e => new SelectListItem() { Text = e, Value = e });
    }
}
```

Comment: Would using the second option causes any errors with how my ticket data was migrated on the first migration?(see configuration.cs). Also where do I put the code for the second option? Do I have to do this for med and high as well?

Comment: Q1: No, because your not changing the data model. Q2: Just replace `Priority = model.priority <-- ERROR` with the 3 lines of code I showed. Q3: No. The first line of code just sets a default value. The second line of code casts the value of your view model enum to the data model enum so its its `TicketVM.Priority.High`, then the value of `priority` will be `Models.Priority.High`

Comment: I'm getting a bunch of errors but I'm suspecting it because you put a semi colon at the end and not a comma? http://pastebin.com/TUFeNwDu

Comment: OK, sorry - you would need to refactor it into a separate method in order to use it inside your object initializer. Give me a moment to test it and I'll update the answer

Comment: and I need to do this for my edit POST and GET method? I got an error (Check pastbin) `Member Priority cannot be initialized . It is not a field or property` `Ticket does not contain the definition for 'priority'` and `Priority cannot reference a type through an expression; Try TicketVm.Priority instead`http://pastebin.com/eqdscwHW

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106866/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-jason-wan).

Answer (score 1):

There is no need in another `Priority` enum in your ViewModel. Just use one from your models adding a corresponding using reference.

However if you still need to assign a value of one enum to a variable of another do it like this `Priority=(int)model.priority`.

Note that you model `Priority` has `Low=0`,`Med=1`, `High=2` while view model `LOW = 3`, `MED = 2`, `HIGH = 1`.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you have two different enum type of `priority`, `TicketVM.Priority`& `Models.Priority` and the error message indicates that system can't implicitly convert these two types.

you could define only one enum type and use it everywhere in your code therefore you don't need enum conversion